# Erro envio de E-mail utilizando Hotmail como CommonsMail Java

Tags: java, email, envio-de-email

Estou com problemas para envio de e-mail utilizando o Outlook, retornando o seguinte erro.

```
Erro Sending the email to the following server failed: smtp.live.com:25
```

Já tentei com a porta `587` e com o smtp `smtp-mail.outlook.com`, porém sem sucesso.

Segue o código que uso para envio.

```
  HtmlEmail email = new HtmlEmail();
    email.setSSLOnConnect(true);
    email.setHostName("smtp-mail.outlook.com");
    email.setSslSmtpPort(587);
    email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator("teste@outlook.com", "12345678"));

    try {
        email.setFrom("teste@outlook.com");

        email.setDebug(true);

        email.setSubject(tituloEmail);
        email.setHtmlMsg(conteudo);
        email.addTo(destinatario);


        email.send();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

geralmente utilizo desta forma com o java mail

```
        Properties propertie = new Properties();  
        propertie.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");  
        propertie.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.live.com");  
        propertie.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "587");  
        propertie.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");  
        propertie.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");  
        propertie.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");  
        propertie.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");  
        session = Session.getDefaultInstance(propertie,  
                    new javax.mail.Authenticator() {  
                         protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()   
                         {  
                               return new PasswordAuthentication("seuemail@hotmail.com", "suasenha");  
                         }  
                    });
```

acredito que é apenas problema no host, tente trocar o

```
smtp-mail.outlook.com
```

por

```
smtp.live.com
```

.

```
HtmlEmail email = new HtmlEmail();
email.setHostName("smtp.live.com");
email.setSslSmtpPort(587);
email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator("seuemail@hotmail.com", "suasenha"));
```

### Editado

Exemplo usando o javaMail

```
public class SendMail {

    public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException {

        final String username = "seuemail@outlook.com";
        final String password = "suasenha";

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "outlook.office365.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
          new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
            }
          });

        try {

            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("seuemail@outlook"));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse("emaildestino@..."));
            message.setSubject("Testando");
            message.setText("Olá");

            Transport.send(message);
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Bom Dia amigo, pode me dar um exemplo mais completo desta situação?

Comment: Bom dia, editei a resposta adicionando um exemplo de envio de email utilizando o javamail